# Editing images using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can I edit images from the internet or pdf files (snapshots) using TikZ to get this non blury good quality graphics in my pdf file?

Comment: TikZ isn't a image processing toolkit, what do you mean by "edit images from the internet to get good quality graphics"?

Comment: @juliohm you're right I've just been reading it in the manual. I sometimes see pdf file with images in it, where they are quite sharp, so if you scroll back you still could see the sharpness of the contours. Sometimes I find jpg's in the internet I want to add to my document. So I sharpen them with some softwares but I don't get the same effect I mentioned.

Comment: Oh then you need to familiarize yourself with rasterized vs. vector image concept. For example http://superuser.com/questions/16434/best-way-to-describe-vector-vs-raster

Comment: @percusse so no way to convert to vector image?

Comment: Some software such as potrace can try hard to convert it but the results are often average. A one-to-one conversion is very very difficult and requires some care. For simple images potrace is quite OK.

Comment: @percusse: +1 This feature is also available in `Inkscape` as `Trace Bitmap`.

Answer (score 1):

Much of the files "off the Internet" are in some low-resolution raster format. PDF *can* render those, but only as low-resolution raster images.

If you want crisp images, look for native PostScript, PDF, or SVG. But many PDFs are really raster scans of documents (particularly for older papers), so that isn't a guarantee either.

Or redo the image youself.